# how to download mysql for pycharm?

Tags: python, mysql, database, pycharm

I am unable to connect MySQL in pycharm python project. I don't know which version I should install to access database and how.
I have to make my python project inventory management system.

Currently I have installed pycharm, python IDE and anaconda

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, the free version of PyCharm doesn't handle SQL.

Comment: This feels like a general software question more than a question about programming.

Answer (score 0):

From Windows Command Prompt / Linux Shell

Install using wheel

```
pip install wheel
```

Download 32 or 64 Bit version from 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

**64-Bit**

```
pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

**32-Bit**

```
pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

Upvote if worked